# htaccess: trouble understanding RewriteCond for URL GET parameters?

Tags: .htaccess

I'll try to explain as best as I can, but I don't fully understand what it is that I'm doing. I have Googled around, and read some information, but at this point I need someone to just give me a kick in the butt and show me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Here is an htaccess script that changes `?page=home&subcat=about&category=me` into `/home/about/me/`.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

(this works just as it's supposed to)

Now, I have a sub-domain, let's call it `sublevel.mywebsite.com` that points to `mywebsite.com/myfolder`

If I go to `sublevel.mywebsite.com` it will act as if `/myfolder/` is `?page=myfolder` - I do not want this for the subdomain, only for the normal site.

I tried adding a redirect condition in front like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder$
```

But, it doesn't seem to be changing very much.

I don't understand what else I can do here, but any help is appreciated? I would also appreciate a small explanation on what is happening if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are rewriting all requests to /index.php, To exclude the subdomain redirection, add the following rule above your RewriteRules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: It works perfectly! If I wanted to only include my domain, and not any subdomains... is there a way to include only a domain, or to exclude all subdomains, without writing each subdomain you want to exclude? I would think including only your domain is easier than excluding all subdomains?